# Excel VBA to find and replace code

Tags: vba, excel

I have a text file, that when I import into Excel looks like this:

[image: Raw Data]

However, I've been trying to put together a VBA code that will do the following:

Column A is the controller.
When a number above "97" appears in column A I simply want to delete it.
I only want to let the first row of "1's" remain.
For every "2" that appears, I firstly want to copy the value in ColB in the "2" row, and paste it over every "3" until I hit the next "2".
Then I'd like to delete the Row's with "2"

So eventually the file should look like:

[image: After Macro]

What I've got so far is:

```
Sub Deleterow97()
'Macro to format text file to readable format for client

    Last = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = Last To 1 Step -1
        If (Cells(i, "A").Value) = "97" Then
            Cells(i, "A").EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next i

    Last = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = Last To 1 Step -1
        If (Cells(i, "A").Value) = "98" Then
            Cells(i, "A").EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next i

    Last = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = Last To 1 Step -1
        If (Cells(i, "A").Value) = "99" Then
            Cells(i, "A").EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next i
    Last = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = Last To 2 Step -1
        If (Cells(i, "A").Value) = "1" Then
            Cells(i, "A").EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next i

Dim CellValue As String
Dim RowCrnt As Integer
Dim RowMax As Integer

With Sheets("Sheet1")   ' Replace Sheet1 by the name of your sheet
    RowMax = .Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    For RowCrnt = 1 To RowMax
        If .Cells(RowCrnt, 1) = "2" Then
            .Range("A:A").Replace What:="3", Replacement:=.Cells(RowCrnt, 2), LookAt:=xlPart, _
                                  SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
                                  ReplaceFormat:=False
        End If
    Next

    Last = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = Last To 2 Step -1
        If (Cells(i, "A").Value) = "2" Then
            Cells(i, "A").EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next i
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: What's wrong with `If (Cells(i, "A").Value) >= 97`?

Comment: How many rows is it ? When you open in excel are you doing Tab deliminted or fixed width?

Comment: Delimited, MS-DOS (PC-8). Delimiters = Comma. Column Data Format = General.
13 Cols and not a fixed amount of rows...could be hundreds or thousands.

Comment: My main issue comes when I get to the replace piece. When I want to replace the "3's" with the 2 value: **For every "2" that appears, I firstly want to copy the value in ColB in the "2" row, and paste it over every "3" until I hit the next "2". Then I'd like to delete the Row's with "2"**

Comment: Sorry, I keep hitting return, but when I try the replace function I get a scientific format number replacing the "3's". I'm not even sure this scientific format number is the "2" Col B equivalent. 
So in Col A I get: A1 is "1" which is fine, but A2 onwards shows: "1.11E+28".....I'm pretty sure its not correctly looking at Col A, finding the "2", copying the value in Col B next to the "2" and pasting that over the "3" in Col A until the next "2" when it then copies the next "2" Col B value and continues....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first, try to do all operations in the same loop. You'll save time. For example you can replace the first thirty lines with that :

```
Last = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
For i = Last To 1 Step -1
    If (Cint(Cells(i, "A").Value)) >= 97 Then
        Cells(i, "A").EntireRow.Delete
    End If

    If i >= 2 AND (Cells(i, "A").Value) = "1" Then
        Cells(i, "A").EntireRow.Delete
    End If

Next i
```

EDIT : so finally

```
Sub formatSheet()
Dim Last As Long
Dim cellToCopy As String

  Last = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
  For i = 2 To Last
    'reverse loop from start to end make it easier to change all "3" below "2"
    cellToCopy = ""
    If (CDbl(Cells(i, "A").Value)) >= 97 And (CDbl(Cells(i, "A").Value)) <= 120 Then
      ' convert to double because you deal with big numbers in column B
      ' and fixe a limit to avoid bugs
        Cells(i, "A").EntireRow.Delete
    End If

    If CDbl(Cells(i, "A").Value) = 1 Then
        Cells(i, "A").EntireRow.Delete
    End If

    If CDbl(Cells(i, "A").Value) = 2 Then
        cellToCopy = Cells(i, "B").Value
        Cells(i, "A").EntireRow.Delete
        Dim j As Long
        j = i
        Do While CDbl(Cells(j, "A").Value) = 3
            Cells(j, "A").Value = cellToCopy
            j = j + 1
        Loop
    End If
  Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Scraaappy, That will definitely help, however my main issue is the find replace piece mentioned above.